African Daisy Seedlings
It’s my first time planting. Do they look okay. I’m worried they are too stretched or weak. I’m planning to transplant my plants in a few days. I also don’t want to thin my seedlings

These look fine - maybe a touch leggy, but not critical. If you can increase the light, it can help, but I wouldn't worry too much.
Please don't transplant them yet - let them develop the first set of true leaves. They will appear after the cotyledons you see here.
